# How do i add and use NLua within my vs solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nlua

I am trying to create a database written in Lua that is separate from my methods that are written in c#. 
The answer I have found so far on how I can run Lua from c# has been "NLua" ( https://github.com/NLua/NLua ) but I have no idea where to start on integrating it into my project so that i can use it as a resource.

there is a README file that gives an example on how to go about "creating a Lua state" in c#:

```
using NLua;

Lua state = new Lua ()
```

From the NLua Files, Which of them are relevant to the use of NLua and how do i apply/install them into my project to do that within a c# class or am I going about this wrong?

So far I have tried placing the LuaRunner and Nlua folders and the whole NLua-Master folder in my project but there must be some extra step to allow me to get "using NLua;" to work.

Comment: This is new to me but there appear to be several NuGet packages available. Perhaps researching a few of these and choosing one to install would do the trick.

Comment: @Mary 
Thanks a ton, so that's how i can add more apps to .NET.

Comment: I've updated the NLua nuget package, should work fine with most platforms https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLua/

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2022 here's how to add NLua to a solution:

- Click Tools on main menu bar.
- Click Nuget Package Manager.
- Click Manage Nuget Packages for Solution.
- In upper left corner of dialog type "NLua" in search box.
- Click Browse above that search box (if not already selected)
- Select NLua in List below the search box.
- To the right of that List is a box where you select which projects you want to have use NLua.
- Make sure "latest stable" version is selected.
- Below that click Install button.
- Add "using NLua;" to the top of your code where needed.
- This link will get you started:
  http://nlua.org/

It works.